# Including <Eigen/Dense> when using /openmp

Tags: eigen

I am pretty new user of Eigen and have run into a weird problem. I am adding  to a C++ project that uses OpenMP (Visual Studio 2012 compiler, /openmp set). I get a compilation error:

> include\eigen\src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h(34): error C3861:
>   'omp_get_max_threads': identifier not found

I have tried to google around for an answer, but have failed to find a solution.  We have another project, not using openmp, where Eigen has been used successfully for a while. Adding /openmp to that project did not trigger the problem. I also tried to disable openmp in Eigen, using the EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE preprocessor directive. The problem persists. All suggestions to solve the problem are more than welcome.

Comment: Make sure that you actually have omp. Add `#ifdef _OPENMP
 std::cout << "Have OMP" << _OPENMP << "\n";
#endif`

Comment: Thanks for the input! Using your snippet, I get "Have OMP200203" :-) Not a big surprise, as the project is using openmp already for other purposes. I have more files including omp.h, and they seem to correctly include a file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include.

Comment: OK, try #ifdef EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP std::cout << "Have EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP\n"; #endif`

Comment: Can you post the command line that's passed to cl?

Comment: Since I cannot include Eigen here, I cannot test for EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP. The command line is not very neat: /Yu"StdAfx.hpp" /GS /GL /analyze- /W4 /wd"4251" /wd"4275" /wd"4505" /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"Win32\Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:fast /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_OPENMP" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /GT /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:SSE2 /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /openmp /Fa"Win32\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Win32\Release\" /Ot /Fp"Win32\Release\MYPROJECT.pch"

Comment: Two notes: a) you're defining `_OPENMP` manually (not just through /openmp, not that important, but try removing it); b) you didn't define `EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE` in the project level. Try defining `EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE` at the project level.

Comment: I had that earlier. But I found a workaround with respect to EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE. By `#ifndef EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE #define EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE #endif` directly before the include, EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP seems to be set correctly to false. For some reason setting it as a preprocessor definition in the project fails.

Comment: So thanks for the input. At least it helps me to compile. Now I just have to figure out why it cannot find omp_get_max_threads(), as I would like to use openmp if possible.

Comment: That's not a good solution. If you later decide to try and enable omp with Eigen, you'll have to go through all your code to remove those bits of code. Are you sure there wasn't a typo when defining at the project level?

Comment: Yes. Tried again now, copy pasting code. The command line now: `/Yu"StdAfx.hpp" /GS /GL /analyze- /W4 /wd"4251" /wd"4275" /wd"4505" /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"Win32\Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:fast /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /GT /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:SSE2 /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /openmp /Fa"Win32\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Win32\Release\" /Ot /Fp"Win32\Release\MYPROJECT.pch" `

Answer (score 1):

Long comment, not really an answer: Something appears to be broken in your project. I'm using Eigen 3.2.9 as a reference, as you haven't specified which version you're using. In Eigen/Core (133) we have

```
#if (defined _OPENMP) && (!defined EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE)
  #define EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP
#endif

#ifdef EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif
```

So, if you properly defined `EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE` in your project, `EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP` shouldn't be defined and `omp.h` shouldn't be included. Additionally, in Parallelizer.h(30):

```
#ifdef EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP
if(m_maxThreads>0)
  *v = m_maxThreads;
else
  *v = omp_get_max_threads();
#else
*v = 1;
#endif
```

So if you had properly defined `EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE`, you would not be getting the error you are getting.

---

Regarding the C3861 error, it means that the compiler is not able to find a declaration for `omp_get_max_threads` (called in Parallelizer.h). As that code is called within a `#ifdef EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP` as is the line `#include <omp.h>` in Core, and `omp_get_num_threads` is only wrapped in an `#if defined( __cplusplus)` you could add a check in Core or omp.h to make sure that the code is active

```
// This is in Eigen/Core
#ifdef EIGEN_HAS_OPENMP
static_assert(0, "OMP FILE IS INCLUDED IN CORE...");
#include <omp.h>
#endif
```

and

```
// This is in omp.h
static_assert(0, "OMP FILE IS PROPERLY INCLUDED...");
_OMPIMP int _OMPAPI
omp_get_num_threads(
    void
    );
```

You should get both as errors if omp is loaded correctly.

Comment: An update on the EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE issue. This was my bad. The cpp using Eigen was included both in my library project and my test project. I was only tweaking the preprocessor config of my library project, meaning that the compilation still failed in the test project. This still does not solve my original problem of using openmp with Eigen, though.

Comment: True. I have forgot to thank you for your kind assistance. I will report back on this question when I find the solution to the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you end up solving your issues?

Comment: No, we are running without OpenMp. It was not given priority to fix this last week, but I will of course report back here when/if solved.